# How to update existing column values in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I just started this programming, apologize for asking this simple question but I am stuck.

I have a data.table called s3:

s3:

```
ClaimID           dx      dxgroup
15nhbfcgcda       113.8   NA
15nhbfcgcda       156.8   NA
15nhbfcgcda       110.8   059
15nhbfcfssa       135.8   NA
15nhb4dfgda       V70.3   NA
15nhbf644da       118.8   042
```

S3 has 30000 rows.

- I want to apply this logic:

  ```
  If dxgroup = NA(
      If dx (fisrt 4 characters match with)= (2024, 2967, 9786,9788,8263)
          then dxgroup = (first 4 character of dx)
      else dx (fisrt 3 characters match with) = (V70, 042,897)
          then dxgroup = (first 3 character of dx)
  else dxgroup = dx
  )
  ```
- Result should be like :

  ```
  ClaimID           dx      dxgroup
  15nhbfcgcda       113.8   113.8
  15nhbfcgcda       156.8   156.8
  15nhbfcgcda       110.8   059
  15nhbfcfssa       135.8   135.8
  15nhb4dfgda       V70.3   V70
  15nhbf644da       118.8   042
  ```
- Please advice ?
- I apologize: It is my first time I am asking something here, so not used to yet. So I did something like this(I have no if this is correct and I got error as well):

  > sample4<-sample3[, dxgroup := { if (dxgroup == NA)
  >
  > - { if (substring(sample3$dx,1,4) == list (2501,2780,4151,5301,5751,6860,7807,7890,9898,9955,9970))  substring(sample3$dx,1,4)
  > - else if (substring(sample3$dx,1,3) == list (042,493,682,850,V72))     substring(sample3$dx,1,3)
  > - else if (substring(sample3$dx,1,4) == list (8540, 8541)) substring(sample3$dx,1,3)
  > - else if (substring(sample3$dx,1,3) == list (043, 044)) 042
  > - else if (substring(sample3$dx,1,3) == list (789) & substring(sample3$dx,1,3) !=  list(7891,7893,78930)) 7890
  > - else if (substring(sample3$dx,1,4) == list (7865) & substring(sample3$dx,1,4) !=    list(78651,78652,78659)) 78650}
  > - else sample3$dx}]
  >     Error in if (dxgroup == NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  >     In addition: Warning message:
  >     In if (dxgroup == NA) { :
  >     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far rather than just asking for code.

Comment: I apologize: It is my first time I am asking something here, so not used to yet. I have added in my question.

Comment: `letters[]` is a built-in vector of letters of the alphabet. So `letters[1:4]` is just `"a" "b" "c" "d"`. You can see this by typing it at the command line.

Comment: I am sorry for being a slow learner.

Comment: hi, you mentioned data.table in your question. Make sure that you are using the `data.table` package or are you confounding it with data.frame?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I was able to do it. Thanks for help and advice. I have one more simple question which I am not bale to find any where....: Can I return 0.00 instead of NA while joining two data.table?

Answer (score 7):

You have the logic all set.

Note that with data.table (well, almost all of `R`), you can wrap the `j` in `{curly brackets}` and the final statement in the brackets is what will be assigned.   eg:

```
DT[,  dxgroup :=  { if (clause1)  
                     {if (foo) beebar else bar}
                  else chewybar
                  } 
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a more `data.table` friendly solution:

```
library(data.table)
s3 <- data.table(s3)
s3[is.na(dxgroup) & (substring(ClaimID, 1, 3) %in% ("V70", "042", "897")), dxgroup := substring(dx, 1, 3)]
s3[is.na(dxgroup) & (substring(ClaimID, 1, 4) %in% ("2024", "2967", "9786", "9788", "8263")), dxgroup := substring(dx, 1, 4)]
s3[is.na(dxgroup), dxgroup := dx] #Default
```

Basically, you work from the most specific condition to the most global condition, as each line in the above script potentially overwrites matches from the previous line.

(I assume you're using the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package.  `data.tables` are different than `data.frames`, and in my opinion much better.)

Comment: Hi @Zach - doesn't the 3rd line fill all dxgroup values, thus rendering the last 2 lines impotent? Unless I'm misunderstand, I think the order must be reversed.

Comment: @RobertMuil I fixed my code— please double check! =D

Comment: Looks good! The description should prob. also be updated to reflect that too (most specific to most global)... Impressive response time BTW :-)

Comment: @RobertMuil Done, and thanks!  Next time try the "suggest edit" feature.

Comment: Welcome - that feature sounds cool, but I don't seem to have it - reputation points required?

Comment: @RobertMuil Maybe.  At some point an "edit" link appears next to the "share" and "flag" links in the bottom left of a question